# Как подставлять разные предметы в анимацию 2D

Tags: c#, unity3d, анимация

Есть анимация атаки мечом главного персонажа. На данный момент существуют одинаковые анимации, но с разными мечами. Как сделать универсальную анимацию под все мечи? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете сделать префаб меча с определенным спрайтом (картинкой), сделать для этого префаба анимацию, а потом просто когда надо менять картинку (в компоненте Image, Sprite Renderer или что там у вас, это не важно) на картинку с нужным вам мечом.